# Is there a callback for port.postMessage() in WebExtenstions

Tags: web-extension

Is there a way to wait till the receiving party processes message sent using [`port.postMessage(message)`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-Port-postMessage)? I'd expect something like callback passed as second argument similarly to [`chrome.scripting.executeScript(injection, callback)`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-executeScript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge not natively but a wrapper is easy to implement. You need a class that will generate a random UID (Unique ID) for each message and store a map `{ [uid]: cb }`. Attach generated UID to the message. Response will also need to contain same UID.